# C# Forms.Timer is using incorrect values for public strings/bools/ints

Tags: c#, timer

Program description: I'm writing a program to use a timer that will continually watch a screen to see if a certain string has changed. if it has, it will store that string in a treeView and run a specific set of functions. It will then use the string listed in the treeView as the "previous transaction" and if a new string is listed in the screen, it will understand we're on a new transaction and repeat the specific functions.

Problem: The timer's .Tick function seems to not be seeing the real time values/text properties of anything in the program. It began by not reading the updated value of the treeView's node from the initial default value that was set upon initialization of the program. Now for some reason the timer is running multiple times (although it's a System.Forms.Timer) and causing an overlap. the first iteration of the timer does not see the node values after they've been updated, but the following ones do and perform correctly.

So, I've tried creating a public bool to utilize, I've tried stopping the timer (this ends the entire .Tick function) with no luck. The timer functions do not recognize an updated value of them at all. Only the value from the beginning of the program.

I cant really post the code as it's in a secure Citrix environment so i cant export out, but it's basically this:

*Edited for more accuracy*

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
  public System.Windows.Forms.Timer _screenWatch = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

  public MainForm()
  {
    _screenWatch.Interval = 5000;
    _screenWatch.Tick += (sender, e) => CheckSplashScreen(sender, e);
    _screenWatch.Enabled = true;
  }

  void CheckSplashScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string currentClaim = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Text)
    Console.WriteLine(currentClaim);
    if (currentClaim != System.GetText(x,y,l))
    {
      GetNewClaim();
    }
  }
}
```

The `MessageBox.Show(currentClaim);` will show the default `Node[0].Text` as it was when the application was started upon it's first timed iteration. As the timer continues it will begin another iteration with the same default values, however, spontaneously another message box pops up immediately in front and has the correct values of the `Node[0].Text`.

It's almost as if there is two timers running simultaneously and one is always incorrect whereas the other is correct.

So I guess my question(s), 1.) How do I make sure the timer's tick actions don't happen until the previous one has finished completely. 2.) Why can't the tick actions see newly updated values in any data type whether it be form controls, ints, bools, strings, etc...?

Comment: A MessageBox does not stop a timer from continuing to run.  currentActiveClaim looks like it's always an empty string.  Why is there even a timer running?  It doesn't seem like a timer type of function.

Comment: Using MessageBox along with a Timer is a really bad idea. For testing use Console logging. For actually using a MessageBox stop and restart the Timer before and after..

Comment: @LarsTech there is a timer because the program is to watch a claims processing system while a processor is going through it. it has to watch the screen to see when a new claim has entered the system to automatically begin running functions on it. Do you know a better way? 

Ok so I've updated the program i'm running with a console log, but the problem persists. the output is showing a single line as incorrect, then 1 line as correct. then 1 line incorrect and another 2 lines correct. this process repeats with 1 incorrect and an ever increasing index of lines with the correct value.

Comment: Please do update the question with the new code..Also tell us a bit more about `GetNewClaim();`

Comment: @TaW `GetNewClaim()` doesn't really matter in this situation. it's simply a placeholder to show that the logic needs to be correct when comparing the currently indexed claim and the one stored as the previous transaction. it basically pulls from another class and gains all the data from the server end of our system.

Comment: OK. Do you recognize the incorrect values? Are they simply late (and if so how just -1 or always the 1st values)  or do they look random?

Comment: @TaW the values are the default value i personally input into the treeview. it's "DCN -". But after the 'GetNewClaim();' portion runs, the node of the treeview in question is a claim number and no longer "DCN -". However, the timer is still recording a console log of "DCN -" mixed with the correct claim number. it's basically listed as line 1: DCN -; line 2: correct; line 3: DCN -; line 4: correct; line 5: correct; line 6: DCN -... lines 7, 8 and 9 would be correct with 10 being incorrect and etc..

Comment: Hm; it ca't put my finger on it; lambda closure keep popping up in my mind but I don't really believe it is it.  - Also: Include a counter in the log to test if Ticks are out of order..

Comment: @Taw How should i do this? I've tried doing a public `int` and just adding, but the int is always seen with the default value of whatever i set it to when declaring it. it's always adding 1 to 0. Suggestions?

Comment: Are other forms involved?

Comment: Hm the counter is at class level and it doesn't get incremented??

Comment: LarsTech yes there is one but its not the main form. @TaW yes the counter is class based. For more context, if i was to emulate the same function with a button click, everything works the way it should. Including an incrementing integer. Thats why im so confused. Ive been spinning my wheels for 2 weeks on this.

Comment: Bottom line is, there isn't enough code that recreates the problem for us.  We're just guessing and throwing darts.

Comment: Do have a look into lambda closure/captures; the posted code doesn't smell of imo, it but the real code might..